# Undefined behaviour at checking a null pointer? (C)

Tags: c, pointers

I am printing down an array in a different way here:

```
char *myString=NULL;
char *Word;
myString= malloc (sizeof (mySchool) +1 ); /* mySchool is a string, which includes ';'*/
strcpy(myString, mySchool);
Word = strtok (myString, ";");
while (1){
    if (Word==NULL)
       break;
    else {
           /* prints */
    }
 Word = strtok(NULL, ";");
}
free (myString);
```

I didn't wrote the printing process because I didn't wanted to bother you with it.

The problem is, I think there is an "undefined behaviour" in `if (Word==NULL)`

I run it about 20 times to check and the program sometimes work very well but sometimes Windows stops working here when the pointer is really null. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the program "stops working" at exactly this line, and not somewhere else? How do you know?

Comment: I've traced the program carefully, I printed signs at some points etc. The program mostly stoppes at that line, and sometimes go past the `if`, break, and crash down at freeing part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Word` in the statement

```
Word = strtok(myString, ";");
```

you should not `malloc` it first (because you will not be able to free it later as the value of the pointer will be changed - resulting in a memory leak, and a segfault when you try to do `free(Word)` later (which you don't show, but you should have, if you use `malloc`). `strtok` returns a pointer to the original string (which gets mangled in the process; it will actually overwrite the tokens with `'\0'`).

How do you allocated `myString`? It should **not** be done with

```
const char* myString="hello;world";
```

because you will run into trouble using `strtok` with a `const` (it is quite possible that the compiler puts the string in "read-only" memory).

That doesn't explain why you are running into a problem; it may have to do with how you defined your `myString`.

**update 3** (with thanks to @JimBalter for useful comments, incorporated below)

Your updated code explains more of your problem.  Your line

```
myString= malloc (sizeof (mySchool));
```

Is very troublesome. Depending on how you defined `mySchool`, it can give you different answers. For example, if you did

```
char *mySchool;
mySchool = malloc(30);
```

You would find

```
sizeof(mySchool) == sizeof( char*)
```

which could be 4, 8, … or whatever the size of a pointer is on your system.

If instead you had written

```
char mySchool[] = "this;is;trouble";
```

then

```
sizeof(mySchool) == 16
```

(the number of characters in the string, plus the terminating `'\0'`).

Thus, it is possible that your `strtok` will run off the end of the string (since there is no terminating `nul`) - and instead of returning a NULL, the next call will return a pointer to space you do not own.

Simple fix:

```
myString = malloc(strlen(mySchool) + 1);
```

and DON'T malloc (or free) `Word`. You just need to declare it as a pointer - it points to space in `myString`, not space of its own.

The following program which incorporates what I described; it works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char *myString;
  char *Word=NULL;
  char mySchool[] = "there;is;something;rotten";
  myString= malloc ( strlen(mySchool) + 1);
  if(myString == NULL) return -1;
  strcpy(myString, mySchool);
  Word = strtok (myString, ";");
  while (1){
    if (Word==NULL)
      break;
    else {
      printf("'%s'\n", Word);
    }
  Word = strtok(NULL, ";");
  }
  free (myString);
  printf("program terminated normally\n");
}
```

This produces, as expected:

```
'there'
'is'
'something'
'rotten'
program terminated normally
```

See if this works for you; then find out how your code is *actually* different...

Comment: added some more information

Comment: The extra information was vital - I think my updated answer should solve your puzzle now.

Comment: sorry for not copying to whole code segment at once. I will do that next time. The problem is, the program crashes now at the `free(myString);` part.

Comment: @user3152199 no problem. Does it still crash, even after you added the `+1`, and got rid of the `malloc` and `free` for `Word`?

Comment: yes, and edited those things at the code in the question too

Comment: Okay, I think I'm too tired and that's some silly mistake I have done. I don't know what it is right know, but I will check it tomorrow and ask here again if I can't get results. Thank you!

Comment: Good night and happy new year.

Comment: `Allocates only enough space for the characters in mySchool, but not for the terminating '\0'` -- this is WRONG. sizeof(char array) includes the NUL. But you should be recommending strlen instead of sizeof. `find out how your code is actually different...` -- the OP is probably using `char*` rather than `char[]` for mySchool.

Comment: @JimBalter thanks for the comments, you are absolutely right. On both counts. Updating...

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you! The problem is solved! :)

Comment: Glad it is solved. As you can see, when it comes to pointer problems in C you really must show code that reproduces the error, including the definition and allocation of all variables used. Something to keep in mind for the next time you turn to SO. Happy New Year!